# Is there any direct payment method in android?

Tags: android

I just want to know is there any payment method directly to a bank 
or i just need to integrate it with methods like paypal,google pay and sites like this.. because the application is paid registration thing
so the client want direct payment with credit cards not with those methods so the use pays tax with it..! I search in the internet all I found is paypal thing stuff.!

Comment: Um, your question doesn't fully make sense.  Paying with credit cards vs not has nothing to do with tax.  But no, there is no built in payments framework in Android.  You'll have to use a 3rd party.  There's dozens of payment processors with libraries, it all depends on who you can get a merchant account with.  I think you need to spend some serious time studying here, taking payments is not simple and you obviously don't know anything about it.  ANd a lot of it is business level decisions, not technical ones.

Comment: @GabeSechan yea i dont know anything about it and i'll delete the question but lets say i used 3rd party like paypal if the user want to pay he need to have profile on paypal too ??? i just want the user to pay easily without making him to register in other sites

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you use an actual payment processor like Square, Authorize.net, or dozens of others they take credit cards.  They're also more difficult to integrate and in some cases require things like bank merchant accounts.  Taking payments is a legally complex task.

Comment: @GabeSechan so if I use does SDK (Square,Authorize.net) or the others that i dont know 
the use can pay automatically without registering in a site 
just puting the card info?